# Whats the best way to manage code snippets on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have fallen in love with visual studio's code snippets toolkit. Is there anything similar on Xcode?

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a loot at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420/any-resharper-equivalent-for-xcode) question which is about similar issues with XCode 3 (code templates, code completion, and more).

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4 has support for code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are. They are under "Edit -> Insert Text Macro".

Or you can simply start typing 'if<ctrl+.>' and this will be expanded into the full if statemenet.