# Delete a User Code Snippet in Xcode 

Tags: xcode, code-snippets

How ??? I can not delete a custom code snippet in Xcode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887404/whats-the-best-way-to-manage-code-snippets-on-xcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265448/remove-default-code-snippets-in-xcode-4

Comment: and how to add them in the first place?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I did these steps :

- Select needed code snippet and press Delete key.
- A pop-up window will appear , and  select Delete button.
- Remember that : this action cannot be undone.

Comment: select snippet, delete-return (⌫↩) is the keyboard-fast way, but make sure you have the right thing selected ;)

Comment: So simple that you don't get it.  Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to do this in Xcode 10, and it wasn't working. I closed the snippets library, reopened it and tried again. Eventually, it worked without having to restart Xcode. If It doesn't seem to work be persistent.

Comment: I had to delete all snippet's fields before being prompt the pop-ip window asking for confirmation of deletion. Weird.

Answer (score 22):

In the Library select the code snippet you want to delete and press Backspace. A confirm dialog will show up, click "Delete".

Answer (score 5):

Good question, I haven't found a way to do it from within Xcode, but they can be deleted from the Finder.  The snippets are stored at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/`.  Each one is a separate file that you can delete.  Unfortunately they're named with an ID and don't give an indication of which one is which.  They're XML files though, so either use a text editor or QuickLook to see the contents and recognise them.

Also, I've had to restart Xcode in order to get the deleted snippets to no longer show up.

Answer (score 4):

I was having trouble, and after messing around a bit it finally worked. You select the user snip and hit the delete key. I tried this multiple times but it didn't work initially. This may be due to me running a prerelease version of Xcode though.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Xcode 10, select snippet from snippet pop-up dialog.
2. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>
3. After that just confirm your removal.

**Note: This process cannot be undo at this moment.**

Answer (score 0):

I was trying forever to delete the useless (to me) C++ ones, but apparently you can only delete the user-created ones in Xcode 10. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

User-created code snippets are located in 
`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`.

If your XCode UI for deletings snippets doesn't work as in my Xcode 10.2.1, you can navigate to this folder and 
either delete all user snippets with `rm *` or use some kind of `cat`/`grep` to find the ones you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode select the code snippet 
Delete title and shortcut and save it after that select the same and press delete a confirmation box pops up asking you to delete or cancel the code snippet.