# Change code completion style in xCode 6/7?

Tags: ios, xcode, syntax, code-completion, hint

I mean for example the following. I start to type "if" and xCode suggests:

```
if (...) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

and I need:

```
if (...)
{
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

Yes, I know that something similar was already asked but show me at least one solution which works in xcode 6/7. It seems all the previous answers are related to previous xcode versions and don't work now.

Comment: What were the previous solutions?  This has never been possible as far as I can remember.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218713/is-there-a-way-to-disable-or-modify-xcodes-code-completion   In the "answer" comment - no such text macro exists to have a possibility to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change standard "if" snippet with http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/

Comment: my answer is "just change standard "if" snippet".
link - it's one of the instruments to do this. IT's event can be done using Xcode only, by creating custom snippets