# Unit test on iPhone Project - How to implement after the Project is complete

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I have an Iphone Project - Pretty huge Project and I cant startover.

I have to add Unit Test's to this Project and what I have seen is people recommend adding it on the start of the Project. Is there any solution for this that I can implement now after the Project is complete.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then write blackbox testing such as integration or validation testing. Unit testing is whitebox testing so your code should be transparent and well-organized for unit testing. That's why people recommend unit testing before starting coding. If you still insist unit testing, I guess you gotta do a lot of refactoring your code to complete the work. So it'd better to find good refactoring tools ( [Any ReSharper equivalent for Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420/any-resharper-equivalent-for-xcode) )